# how to fix getting { upload failed with 400 - Generic/unknown HTTP error } when trying to upload login form

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I am trying to make login feature inside the game.
What I am trying to do is when I am logged in , I want player properties to return back eg {health, ammo, power .... }
I already test it with postman. Its working fine in the postman but not in the unity.

Here are images I tried in the postman.

[Authorization in post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Zg0.png)

[Header in the post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvynu.png)

[Body in the post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMZdY.png)

Here are my codes

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string inputUserName;
    public string inputPassword;

string loginURL = "http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/";

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(login("09256358599", "123456789"));
}


IEnumerator login(string username, string password)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("phoneNumber", "09256358599");
    form.AddField("password", "123456789");

    var json = "{\"phoneNumber\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/", json))
    {

        byte[] bytes = GetBytes(json);
        UploadHandlerRaw uH = new UploadHandlerRaw(bytes);
        www.uploadHandler = uH;

        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        www.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/json";

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Upload failed with: {0} - {1}", www.responseCode, www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("FORM UPLOAD COMPLEˇE");
        }
    }
}



 private byte[] GetBytes(string json)
 {
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    return bytes;
 }
}
```

And how can I return the player properties . What I am doing now is simply debug.log.

Comment: please @khant can you add exception message to your post ?

Comment: check  authorization in the header ( Exemple : "Authorization", "Basic MG9haXJsOXUwMmNwUzNWd24waDc6blZRYUFyS25kZ3FBcmZmTkZBeTNxcUZFeWZZbFJWeUl4VXJQTDU2NQ==" )

Comment: @sayahimad can u show me the way?
I am really new to unity and I am stuck here for a really long time

Comment: You need to encrypt the password portion most likely.

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu how do you create the Authorization header value in postman?

Comment: @GeorgeChond I don't create values ! The thing is that these urls are coming from the backend developer. I think the values are auto generated. { or maybe not }

Comment: @BugFinder I am passing in the username and password at the start. 
When I search for error 400 ! Google said its due to  invalid syntax . Do you think I need to change the content type for body.
What I am doing now is that I am setting requestHeader's { content-type } to { application/json } Do I also need it for body?

Comment: no, its just a header but you need to put the header in correctly and the password gets converted so isnt a string of myuser:password, but say sjffHDu32nr35..

Answer (score 1):

You need to call SetRequestHeader to set the Authorization header

it mays look like this

```
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/", json))
    {
       String username = "abc";
       String password = "123";
       String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
       www.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu this code is exactly what I use in my projects.  Why not add some debugging to compare the encoded string above, to the one from postman, check you have space between Basic and the encoded authorization string..

Comment: What should I do if it wasn't the same ? 

this one coming from unity 
{ MDkyNTYzNTg1OTk6MTIzNDU2Nzg5 }

this one is from post man
{ MDk3Nzc0NDkzOTI6MTIzNDU2Nzg= }

@BugFinder

Comment: Well when i put the value you listed in postman, I also get MDkyNTYzNTg1OTk6MTIzNDU2Nzg5, so you did something different in postman, maybe a space at the end?

Comment: now the encoded values become the same.
but there another error ! { error code 415 }

There error code 415 when I remove this line 
{ www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); }
When I add above line
there is error type 400

Should I remove that line or still needed?

@BugFinder

Comment: Well,whatever you originally had in postman that was different was needed to make it work - this shouldnt be a guessing game, and working via comments is not a practical SO issue

Comment: PS look up your return coded, 415 suggests you sent junk not that it wasnt authorized

Answer (score 0):

try to add the authorization to your header

```
var headers = new Hashtable();
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+ Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)); 
using (UnityWebRequest www = 
UnityWebRequest.Post("http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/", json, headers))
{
 // your code
}
```

Comment: cannot add header into this line 
UnityWebRequest.Post("http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/", json, headers));

it will show error message {cannot convert string to system.collecton.generic }

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the `WWWForm form` object in the `UnityWebRequest.Post` method. 
Try to create a new `UnityWebRequest` object, encode the json string to bytes and also create a `DownloadHandlerBuffer` (to read the json object you want back)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string inputUserName;
    public string inputPassword;

    string loginURL = "http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/userLogin/";

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(login("09256358599", "123456789"));
    }

    IEnumerator login(string username, string password)
    {
        var json = "{\"phoneNumber\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(loginURL, "POST");
        var bodyRaw = GetBytes(json);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return request.Send();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Upload failed with: {0} - {1}", request.responseCode, request.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("FORM UPLOAD COMPLETE");
            var results = request.downloadHandler.data; //this will contain the JSON data you 'll need
        }
    }

    private byte[] GetBytes(string json)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    }
}
```